# Don't show the wrapper from an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular directive. When I call it on my page, it still shows the outer wrapper. How can I get rid of this wrapper?

**directives.js**

```
myApp.directive('myThingy', function(){
  return {
    template: "<div>HELLO!</div>"
  }
});
```

**my_page.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <my-thingy></my-thingy>
  </body>
</html>
```

**The DOM in the browser:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <my-thingy>
      <div>HELLO!</div>
    </my-thingy>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I get rid of those `<my-thingy>` tags, and just show the directive's result?

**Desired DOM (there are no my-thingy tags):**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>HELLO!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add option `replace`

```
myApp.directive('myThingy', function(){
  return {
    replace: true,
    template: "<div>HELLO!</div>"
  }
});
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q15Grg0bbgnHRT1ke8n0?p=preview)